# CAST always returns 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm executing this TSQL Code:

```
DECLARE @myString varchar;
SET @myString = '123.0'
SELECT CAST(@myString as decimal(25,10))
```

But I keep getting 1.00000 as an result
Changing myString to '123' doesn't change that.

Any advise on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

*ALWAYS* use length when using `varchar()` (and related types) in MySQL.  The default is `1` in this context.  So this fixes your problem:

```
DECLARE @myString varchar(255);
SET @myString = '123.0';
SELECT CAST(@myString as decimal(25,10));
```

You are getting `1`, because your code is interpreted as

```
DECLARE @myString varchar(1);
SET @myString = '123.0';
SELECT CAST(@myString as decimal(25,10));
```

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) is not shy about this:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the varchar declareation

```
DECLARE @myString varchar(10);
SET @myString = '123.0'
SELECT CAST(@myString as decimal(25,10))
```